# Entity framework unique property of child entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I use model similar to popular Blog/Post EntityFramework examples:

```
public class Blog 
{ 
    public int BlogId { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
} 

public class Post 
{ 
    public int PostId { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public string Content { get; set; } 

    public int BlogId { get; set; } 
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; } 
}
```

I need to have Post.Title to be unique per Blog.
For now, I have

```
protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity
```

Here I need to implement logic to check for duplicates, which is not obvious because I need to check Posts.Local and Posts in DB, also logic depends on entityEntry.Status. Is this the only possible way to implement this restriction or maybe some more elegant solution exists?

Comment: If you set BlogId and Title to be a unique constraint on the Post table then that will give you the necessary validation at DB level. I'm not sure how to annotate this in EF though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding a unique index on them:

```
[Index("IdAndTitle", 1, IsUnique = true)]
public string Title { get; set; }

[Index("IdAndTitle", 2]
public int BlogId { get; set; }
```

Comment: That will make Title unique across all Posts. According to the question it needs to be unique across a blog.

Comment: Not recommended to keep these storage annotations in your entity classes, move it to the Context Class and use Fluent API instead